# Decomposing a matrix as a product of non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $X\in \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ <strike>is positive semi-definite</strike>. Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$ be some integer greater than one. Under what conditions can we find two matrices $A,B\in \mathbb{M}_{n\times m}(\mathbb{C}) $ such that $X=AB^*?$ (the star is the conjugate transpose).

This is a minor point which shows up in a project I'm working on. I would really like it if the answer was "Always, given that $m\geq n$", but I'm not sure how to show that.

Answer (score 1):

If $m = n$, then because $X$ is positive semi-definite, it has a unique positive semi-definite square root $A$ and so $X = A^2 = AA^{*}$. If $m > n$, enlarge $A$ by adding $m - n$ extra columns of zeros at the end. You will still have $X = AA^{*}$.

Comment: More interestingly, if $X$ has rank $k$, we can find an $n \times k$ matrix $A$ such that $X = AA^*$.

Comment: Thank you levap. Another instance of the problem is if X is not necessarily positive semi-definite. What can we say in that case?

Comment: For some reason, I implicitly assumed that you want some relation between $A$ and $B$. In general, you can write any matrix $X \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ as $X = AB^{*}$ where $A,B \in M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{F})$ and $m > m$. Just take $A$ to be $X$ padded with extra zero columns at the end and $B = I_{n}$ padded with extra zero columns at the end.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm very poorly phrasing my questions. You are right in assuming that I actually want some relation between $A$ and $B$. I will modify the question in a little bit to reflect what I actually wanted to ask.

Comment: It is better that you ask a separate question in order to avoid too many edits.